# flake8 on all files under specific subdirectories

Tags: python, flake8

I'm trying to use flake8 only on 3 specific sub directories: `features_v2`, `rules_v2` and `indicators_v2`.

In order to test if my pattern is correct I tried applying it only to features_v2 at first. so I came up with this pattern: `exclude = ^(?!.*features_v2).*$` but sadly it doesn't seems to work. Is flake8 does not support lookaround, or it does and I did something wrong?

Is there a better way to use flake on 3 different subdirectories?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

flake8's `exclude` is not a regex but a [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) -- it cannot support what you're looking for

may I suggest instead to run flake8 on the directories you want?

```
flake8 features_v2 rules_v2 indicators_v2
```

---

disclaimer: I maintain flake8

Comment: How do you check for all subdirectories? Is it `flake8 ./*` or `flake8 **/**` or something else?

Comment: I believe I got my answer it's: `flake8 **/*.py`